# Performance issue with adding/deleting a lot of routes on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I have about 7k route records to add/delete frequently on VPN connecting/disconnecting. Using `route add/delete` would take several minutes, which is certainly annoying.

I have tried to increase concurrency and get a speed boost at 20~40%, but it also increase failure rate adding/deleting a route (and possibly failure without an error).

Is there a way to make this faster while keeping it stable?
I've noticed an API set under [Routing Table Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381167(v=vs.85).aspx) but it seems that it's only available on server version of Windows (I need it to work on normal Windows installation).

Comment: Probably would help to use CreateIpForwardEntry? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365860(v=vs.85).aspx Still 7k routes sounds quite wild

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sounds promising, will give it a try. Thanks! The routes contains all the IP records allocated to China, which is used to optimize the "internal" network experience while using a VPN.